# Delivery Network Optimization

Tags: python, optimization

I used this code and got an error. Can you help?

### ERROR:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 66
     64 # Define decision variables
     65 x = LpVariable.dicts("x", [(i, j) for i in store_locations for j in store_locations], lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
---> 66 y = LpVariable.dicts("y", [(i, j) for i in store_locations for j in warehouse_locations], cat='Binary')
     67 t = LpVariable.dicts("t", [(i) for i in store_locations], lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
     69 # Define the objective function

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py:418, in LpVariable.dicts(cls, name, indices, lowBound, upBound, cat, indexStart, indexs)
    416 if len(indices) == 0:
    417     for i in index:
--> 418         d[i] = LpVariable(
    419             name % tuple(indexStart + [str(i)]), lowBound, upBound, cat
    420         )
    421 else:
    422     for i in index:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is the code I used

```
from pulp import *

# Store locations
store_locations = {
    1: (54.13917237, 10.16301447),
    2: (5.163117855, 18.37136899),
    3: (58.10773412, 97.325872),
    4: (16.60663876, 73.67529068),
    5: (10.92151473, 26.90262604),
    6: (40.2830426, 49.00596112),
    7: (95.90679501, 31.25379214),
    8: (38.80688537, 61.84963412),
    9: (50.77362816, 41.71229884),
    10: (16.12104517, 4.174152112),
    11: (30.57252604, 25.66416139),
    12: (88.65418483, 28.60340585),
    13: (76.15833298, 52.06010201),
    14: (57.99079029, 58.29016932),
    15: (80.11801005, 80.74242101),
    16: (90.87902761, 90.97690565),
    17: (2.587207522, 45.80849397),
    18: (74.04980053, 2.986131158),
    19: (71.70911665, 37.25817058),
    20: (22.37191714, 94.53074723),
    21: (24.10112206, 11.06658123),
    22: (42.27800052, 9.141860385),
    23: (58.3280586, 76.15907608),
    'W1': (71.25359844, 18.21268482),
    'W2': (57.24219473, 82.66876117)
}

# Distance matrix
warehouse_locations = [
    [0, 50, 87, 74, 46, 41, 47, 54, 32, 38, 28, 39, 47, 48, 75, 89, 63, 21, 32, 90, 30, 12, 51, 14],
    [50, 0, 95, 56, 10, 47, 92, 55, 51, 18, 26, 84, 79, 66, 98, 112, 28, 71, 69, 78, 20, 38, 65, 52],
    [87, 95, 0, 48, 85, 52, 76, 40, 56, 102, 77, 75, 49, 39, 28, 33, 76, 96, 62, 36, 93, 90, 25, 66],
    [74, 56, 48, 0, 47, 34, 90, 25, 47, 70, 50, 85, 63, 44, 64, 76, 31, 91, 71, 54, 72, 84, 39, 56],
    [46, 10, 85, 47, 0, 38, 84, 50, 45, 15, 22, 74, 69, 56, 88, 101, 22, 62, 60, 68, 13, 33, 57, 43],
    [41, 47, 52, 34, 38, 0, 57, 21, 12, 53, 32, 64, 44, 31, 47, 61, 34, 60, 38, 16, 53, 47, 15, 17],
    [47, 92, 76, 90, 84, 57, 0, 67, 73, 85, 68, 9, 28, 50, 28, 10, 73, 54, 63, 24, 83, 80, 44, 68],
    [54, 55, 40, 25, 50, 21, 67, 0, 23, 54, 35, 51, 29, 16, 29, 44, 19, 69, 45, 23, 63, 59, 15, 34],
    [32, 51, 56, 47, 45, 12, 73, 23, 0, 46, 25, 53, 31, 23, 47, 60, 33, 54, 27, 16, 46, 44, 6, 22],
    [38, 18, 102, 70, 15, 53, 85, 54, 46, 0, 21, 79, 73, 61, 93, 107, 33, 85, 73, 81, 31, 47, 78, 67],
    [28, 26, 77, 50, 20, 25, 66, 37, 26, 26, 0, 58, 53, 43, 74, 89, 34, 49, 43, 69],
    [39, 84, 75, 85, 78, 52, 8, 60, 77, 77, 58, 0, 27, 43, 53, 62, 88, 29, 19, 69],
    [47, 79, 49, 63, 70,36, 29, 39, 27, 77, 53, 27, 0],
    [48, 66, 39, 44, 57, 20, 47, 20, 18, 68, 43, 43, 19, 0, 0],
    [75, 98, 28, 64, 88, 51, 52, 45, 49, 100, 74, 53, 29, 32, 0, 0],
    [89, 112, 33, 76, 102, 66, 60, 60, 64, 115, 89, 62, 42, 46, 15, 0],
    [63, 28, 76, 31, 21, 38, 94, 40, 48, 44, 34, 88, 74, 57, 85, 99, 0],
    [21, 71, 96, 91, 68, 57, 36, 69, 45, 58, 49, 29, 49, 58, 78, 90, 83, 0],
    [32, 69, 62, 66, 62, 34, 25, 41, 21, 65, 43, 19, 15, 25, 44, 57, 70, 34, 0],
    [90, 78, 36, 22, 69, 49, 97, 37, 60, 91, 69, 93, 69, 51, 59, 69, 53, 105, 76, 0],
    [30, 20, 93, 63, 21, 41, 75, 53, 41, 11, 16, 67, 66, 58, 89, 104, 41, 51, 54, 83, 0],
    [12, 38, 90, 69, 36, 40, 58, 53, 34, 27, 20, 50, 55, 52, 81, 95, 54, 32, 41, 88, 0],
    [66, 79, 21, 42, 68, 33, 59, 24, 35, 83, 58, 56, 30, 18, 22, 36, 63, 75, 41, 40, 0],
    [19, 66, 80, 78, 61, 44, 28, 54, 31, 57, 41, 20, 34, 42, 63, 75, 74, 15, 19, 91, 0],
    [73, 83, 15, 42, 72, 38, 64, 28, 41, 89, 63, 63, 36, 24, 23, 35, 66, 81, 48, 37, 0, 0]
]

# Define the problem
prob = LpProblem("Store_Location_Problem", LpMinimize)

# Define decision variables
x = LpVariable.dicts("x", [(i, j) for i in store_locations for j in store_locations], lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
y = LpVariable.dicts("y", [(i, j) for i in store_locations for j in warehouse_locations], cat='Binary')
t = LpVariable.dicts("t", [(i) for i in store_locations], lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# Define the objective function
prob += lpSum([distances[i-1][j-1]*x[(i,j)] for i in store_locations for j in store_locations])

# Define the constraints
for i in store_locations:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i,j)] for j in store_locations]) == 1
for j in warehouse_locations:
    prob += lpSum([y[(i,j)] for i in store_locations]) == 2
for i in store_locations:
    for j in warehouse_locations:
        prob += x[(i,j)] <= y[(i,j)]*100
for i in store_locations:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i,j)] for j in store_locations]) - lpSum([x[(j,i)] for j in store_locations]) == 0
for j in warehouse_locations:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i,j)] for i in store_locations]) - lpSum([x[(j,i)] for i in store_locations]) == 0
for i in store_locations:
    prob += t[i] >= 0
    prob += t[i] <= 300
for i in store_locations:
    for j in store_locations:
        if i != j:
            prob += t[i] + distances[i-1][j-1] - t[j] <= 300*(1 - x[(i,j)])

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Print the results
print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])
print("Total Cost of Transportation = ", value(prob.objective))
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: This is way more code than you need - `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` means you're probably trying to set a dictionary key to be a list somewhere

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please specify: are W1 and W2 actually warehouses? Why is `distances` not defined? What do `x`, `y` and `t` actually represent? Can you describe each of your constraints in plain language? We want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. The error is exactly correct, look at the output of:

```
# Store locations
store_locations = {
    1: (54.13917237, 10.16301447),
    2: (5.163117855, 18.37136899),
    3: (58.10773412, 97.325872),
    4: (16.60663876, 73.67529068),
    5: (10.92151473, 26.90262604),
    6: (40.2830426, 49.00596112),
    7: (95.90679501, 31.25379214),
    8: (38.80688537, 61.84963412),
    9: (50.77362816, 41.71229884),
    10: (16.12104517, 4.174152112),
    11: (30.57252604, 25.66416139),
    12: (88.65418483, 28.60340585),
    13: (76.15833298, 52.06010201),
    14: (57.99079029, 58.29016932),
    15: (80.11801005, 80.74242101),
    16: (90.87902761, 90.97690565),
    17: (2.587207522, 45.80849397),
    18: (74.04980053, 2.986131158),
    19: (71.70911665, 37.25817058),
    20: (22.37191714, 94.53074723),
    21: (24.10112206, 11.06658123),
    22: (42.27800052, 9.141860385),
    23: (58.3280586, 76.15907608),
    'W1': (71.25359844, 18.21268482),
    'W2': (57.24219473, 82.66876117)
}

# Distance matrix
warehouse_locations = [
    [0, 50, 87, 74, 46, 41, 47, 54, 32, 38, 28, 39, 47, 48, 75, 89, 63, 21, 32, 90, 30, 12, 51, 14],
    [50, 0, 95, 56, 10, 47, 92, 55, 51, 18, 26, 84, 79, 66, 98, 112, 28, 71, 69, 78, 20, 38, 65, 52],
    [87, 95, 0, 48, 85, 52, 76, 40, 56, 102, 77, 75, 49, 39, 28, 33, 76, 96, 62, 36, 93, 90, 25, 66],
    [74, 56, 48, 0, 47, 34, 90, 25, 47, 70, 50, 85, 63, 44, 64, 76, 31, 91, 71, 54, 72, 84, 39, 56],
    [46, 10, 85, 47, 0, 38, 84, 50, 45, 15, 22, 74, 69, 56, 88, 101, 22, 62, 60, 68, 13, 33, 57, 43],
    [41, 47, 52, 34, 38, 0, 57, 21, 12, 53, 32, 64, 44, 31, 47, 61, 34, 60, 38, 16, 53, 47, 15, 17],
    [47, 92, 76, 90, 84, 57, 0, 67, 73, 85, 68, 9, 28, 50, 28, 10, 73, 54, 63, 24, 83, 80, 44, 68],
    [54, 55, 40, 25, 50, 21, 67, 0, 23, 54, 35, 51, 29, 16, 29, 44, 19, 69, 45, 23, 63, 59, 15, 34],
    [32, 51, 56, 47, 45, 12, 73, 23, 0, 46, 25, 53, 31, 23, 47, 60, 33, 54, 27, 16, 46, 44, 6, 22],
    [38, 18, 102, 70, 15, 53, 85, 54, 46, 0, 21, 79, 73, 61, 93, 107, 33, 85, 73, 81, 31, 47, 78, 67],
    [28, 26, 77, 50, 20, 25, 66, 37, 26, 26, 0, 58, 53, 43, 74, 89, 34, 49, 43, 69],
    [39, 84, 75, 85, 78, 52, 8, 60, 77, 77, 58, 0, 27, 43, 53, 62, 88, 29, 19, 69],
    [47, 79, 49, 63, 70,36, 29, 39, 27, 77, 53, 27, 0],
    [48, 66, 39, 44, 57, 20, 47, 20, 18, 68, 43, 43, 19, 0, 0],
    [75, 98, 28, 64, 88, 51, 52, 45, 49, 100, 74, 53, 29, 32, 0, 0],
    [89, 112, 33, 76, 102, 66, 60, 60, 64, 115, 89, 62, 42, 46, 15, 0],
    [63, 28, 76, 31, 21, 38, 94, 40, 48, 44, 34, 88, 74, 57, 85, 99, 0],
    [21, 71, 96, 91, 68, 57, 36, 69, 45, 58, 49, 29, 49, 58, 78, 90, 83, 0],
    [32, 69, 62, 66, 62, 34, 25, 41, 21, 65, 43, 19, 15, 25, 44, 57, 70, 34, 0],
    [90, 78, 36, 22, 69, 49, 97, 37, 60, 91, 69, 93, 69, 51, 59, 69, 53, 105, 76, 0],
    [30, 20, 93, 63, 21, 41, 75, 53, 41, 11, 16, 67, 66, 58, 89, 104, 41, 51, 54, 83, 0],
    [12, 38, 90, 69, 36, 40, 58, 53, 34, 27, 20, 50, 55, 52, 81, 95, 54, 32, 41, 88, 0],
    [66, 79, 21, 42, 68, 33, 59, 24, 35, 83, 58, 56, 30, 18, 22, 36, 63, 75, 41, 40, 0],
    [19, 66, 80, 78, 61, 44, 28, 54, 31, 57, 41, 20, 34, 42, 63, 75, 74, 15, 19, 91, 0],
    [73, 83, 15, 42, 72, 38, 64, 28, 41, 89, 63, 63, 36, 24, 23, 35, 66, 81, 48, 37, 0, 0]
]

a = [(i, j) for i in store_locations for j in warehouse_locations]
print(a)
```

It's not totally clear to me exactly what you wanted from that, but the first result is `(1, [0, 50, 87, 74, 46, 41, 47, 54, 32, 38, 28, 39, 47, 48, 75, 89, 63, 21, 32, 90, 30, 12, 51, 14])` and you can't have a list in a dictionary key. Besides, [the library](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/a7684ac90d93dc3bca382d90841a9ab5f398b50f/pulp/pulp.py#L378) expects a list of strings, which is even further removed from what you have provided it with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your data structure is set up correctly.  There is no information on what the `warehouse_location` structure holds.  It says "distance matrix" but from what to what isn't clear and it isn't clear why the rows (assumed) are different lengths.

So, that probably needs to be fixed.

In the line causing the error (line 66) you are passing in "for `j` in `warehouse_locations`..."  But, `warehouse_locations` is a list of lists, so you are passing in an entire list here (one of the sub-lists), which isn't legal